# WCF Client reading JSONP responses

Tags: wcf, jsonp

I'm writing a simple client for a web service using WCF. Unfortunately, the web service only answers with JSONP messages, not plain JSON.

Is that possible to use built-in features from .NET 4.0 to do this or do I need to extend something else to strip function name, { and } from the answer I get from the server? I know how to read JSON responses, but not JSONP yet.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you need is a custom message encoder. On the server side, it's the encoder which adds the padding (function call) to the response, so you need something similar on the client side to remove that padding before handling the message (likely delegating it to another encoder). The other thing you'll need to worry about at the encoder is that often the content-type used for JSONP (application/x-javascript) is not recognized as a JSON content-type (because it's not, it's a function call), so the encoder should also "translate" that content-type into one which is understood by the encoder to which the call is delegated.

The code below shows an example of such an encoder. The service has been modified to always wrap the result, as you mentioned your service does.

```
public class StackOverflow_11255528
{
    [ServiceContract]
    public interface ICalculator
    {
        [WebGet(ResponseFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json)]
        int Add(int x, int y);
        [WebGet(ResponseFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json)]
        int Subtract(int x, int y);
    }
    [ServiceContract]
    public class CalculatorService
    {
        [WebGet(ResponseFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json)]
        public Stream Add(int x, int y)
        {
            return ReturnWrapped(x + y);
        }

        [WebGet(ResponseFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json)]
        public Stream Subtract(int x, int y)
        {
            return ReturnWrapped(x - y);
        }

        private Stream ReturnWrapped(int result)
        {
            string callback = "Something";
            string response = string.Format("{0}({1});", callback, result);
            WebOperationContext.Current.OutgoingResponse.ContentType = "application/x-javascript";
            return new MemoryStream(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(response));
        }
    }
    public class JsonpAwareClientMessageEncodingBindingElement : MessageEncodingBindingElement
    {
        WebMessageEncodingBindingElement webEncoding;

        public JsonpAwareClientMessageEncodingBindingElement()
        {
            this.webEncoding = new WebMessageEncodingBindingElement();
        }

        public override MessageEncoderFactory CreateMessageEncoderFactory()
        {
            return new JsonpAwareClientMessageEncoderFactory(this.webEncoding.CreateMessageEncoderFactory());
        }

        public override MessageVersion MessageVersion
        {
            get { return this.webEncoding.MessageVersion; }
            set { this.webEncoding.MessageVersion = value; }
        }

        public override BindingElement Clone()
        {
            return new JsonpAwareClientMessageEncodingBindingElement();
        }

        public override IChannelFactory<TChannel> BuildChannelFactory<TChannel>(BindingContext context)
        {
            context.BindingParameters.Add(this);
            return context.BuildInnerChannelFactory<TChannel>();
        }

        class JsonpAwareClientMessageEncoderFactory : MessageEncoderFactory
        {
            private MessageEncoderFactory factory;

            public JsonpAwareClientMessageEncoderFactory(MessageEncoderFactory factory)
            {
                this.factory = factory;
            }

            public override MessageEncoder Encoder
            {
                get { return new JsonpAwareClientMessageEncoder(this.factory.Encoder); }
            }

            public override MessageVersion MessageVersion
            {
                get { return this.factory.MessageVersion; }
            }
        }

        class JsonpAwareClientMessageEncoder : MessageEncoder
        {
            private MessageEncoder encoder;

            public JsonpAwareClientMessageEncoder(MessageEncoder encoder)
            {
                this.encoder = encoder;
            }

            public override string ContentType
            {
                get { return this.encoder.ContentType; }
            }

            public override string MediaType
            {
                get { return this.encoder.MediaType; }
            }

            public override MessageVersion MessageVersion
            {
                get { return this.encoder.MessageVersion; }
            }

            public override bool IsContentTypeSupported(string contentType)
            {
                if (contentType == "application/x-javascript")
                {
                    contentType = "application/json";
                }

                return this.encoder.IsContentTypeSupported(contentType);
            }

            public override Message ReadMessage(ArraySegment<byte> buffer, BufferManager bufferManager, string contentType)
            {
                if (contentType == "application/x-javascript")
                {
                    contentType = "application/json";
                }

                byte openParenthesis = (byte)'(';
                byte closeParenthesis = (byte)')';
                int startOfParenthesis = buffer.Offset;
                int count = buffer.Count;
                while (buffer.Array[startOfParenthesis] != openParenthesis)
                {
                    startOfParenthesis++;
                    count--;
                }

                // Skipped 'Func', now skipping '('
                startOfParenthesis++;
                count--;

                // Now need to trim the closing parenthesis and semicolon, if any
                int endOfParenthesis = buffer.Offset + buffer.Count - 1;
                while (buffer.Array[endOfParenthesis] != closeParenthesis)
                {
                    endOfParenthesis--;
                    count--;
                }

                // Skipped back to ')', now remove it
                endOfParenthesis--;
                count--;

                return this.encoder.ReadMessage(new ArraySegment<byte>(buffer.Array, startOfParenthesis, count), bufferManager, contentType);
            }

            public override Message ReadMessage(Stream stream, int maxSizeOfHeaders, string contentType)
            {
                throw new NotSupportedException("Streamed mode not supported");
            }

            public override ArraySegment<byte> WriteMessage(Message message, int maxMessageSize, BufferManager bufferManager, int messageOffset)
            {
                return this.encoder.WriteMessage(message, maxMessageSize, bufferManager, messageOffset);
            }

            public override void WriteMessage(Message message, Stream stream)
            {
                throw new NotSupportedException("Streamed mode not supported");
            }
        }
    }
    public static void Test()
    {
        string baseAddress = "http://" + Environment.MachineName + ":8000/Service";
        ServiceHost host = new ServiceHost(typeof(CalculatorService), new Uri(baseAddress));
        WebHttpBinding binding = new WebHttpBinding { CrossDomainScriptAccessEnabled = true };
        host.AddServiceEndpoint(typeof(CalculatorService), binding, "").Behaviors.Add(new WebHttpBehavior());
        host.Open();
        Console.WriteLine("Host opened");

        WebClient c = new WebClient();
        Console.WriteLine(c.DownloadString(baseAddress + "/Add?x=5&y=8&callback=Func"));

        CustomBinding clientBinding = new CustomBinding(
            new JsonpAwareClientMessageEncodingBindingElement(),
            new HttpTransportBindingElement { ManualAddressing = true });
        ChannelFactory<ICalculator> factory = new ChannelFactory<ICalculator>(clientBinding, new EndpointAddress(baseAddress));
        factory.Endpoint.Behaviors.Add(new WebHttpBehavior());
        ICalculator proxy = factory.CreateChannel();
        Console.WriteLine(proxy.Subtract(456, 432));

        Console.Write("Press ENTER to close the host");
        Console.ReadLine();
        host.Close();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

There is no direct way which I know but lets first try to understand difference between a JSON and JSONP

```
//JSON
{"prop":"val"}
//JSONP
func({"prop":"val"});
```

To get the JSON string you could simply strip every thing in between the "(" and ")" braces and then use different JSON libraries to convert it in to objects.

```
string jsonString = Regex.Match(jsonpString, @"\(([^)]*)\)").Groups[1].Value
```

Comment: I know... but which part of WCF will I need to extend in order to implement my own deserialization class?